# Hosting both flask + vite-react app on same server - Nginx error "404" or "permission denied"?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, vite

I am trying to setup both a flask + vite-react app on the same server using nginx. The flask app works flawlessly, however the react app (which will only show on /portfolio) doesn't seem to work

Heres my nginx config file:

```
server {
    server_name spiralapi.dev www.spiralapi.dev;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/server.sock;
    }

    location /portfolio {
        root /root/webserver/portfolio;
        index index.html;
        
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to nginx so i'm not sure exactly what the issue is. I have tried changing folder perms for /webserver and /webserver/portfolio, but to no avail.

For context, /portfolio is the npm run build (or 'dist') folder

Here is the error in the log file:
`[crit] 31634#31634: *266 stat() "/root/webserver/portfolio" failed (13: Permission denied), client: redacted, server: spiralapi.dev, request: "GET /portfolio HTTP/1.1", host: "spiralapi.dev", referrer: "https://spiralapi.dev/"`

Thank you for reading!

**UPDATE:**
Ended up moving my /portfolio folder to a shared location (/var/www), now I am receiving error 404 with no permission errors showing in log.

Comment: Have you change your nginx location's root config when you change your project path. And make sure you've reload your config after the modification.

Comment: @LF-DevJourney I changed the location of the root in the nginx config to /var/www/portfolio and reloaded nginx with `nginx -s reload`, still nothing

Comment: show the 404 error log.

Comment: if possible, show `ls -l /var/www/portfolio` here.

Comment: @LF-DevJourney You can view it here https://prnt.sc/dVuoJ_gHLxct

Comment: Add nginx debug log to nginx error_log, to check which path it used.

Comment: @LF-DevJourney i tried adding `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;` to my nginx file, but didn't see much useful information https://prnt.sc/WThZvmMrKRn-

Comment: Also add this ` log_not_found on; #enables or disables messages in error_log about files not found on disk. 
 rewrite_log on;`

Comment: @LF-DevJourney im seeing errors like `trying to use file: "/portfolio" "/var/www/portfolio/portfolio"` and `trying to use file: "=404" "/var/www/portfolio=404"`, looks like its looking for a portfolio folder inside the portfolio folder?

Comment: Then you can just remoe one in your locaiton's root.